# Scanner.nextInt(); is accepting two inputs (I think)

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a console program that allows you to view the list of all students and their information and search the list with your specified entry. 
I am currently working on the part where-in you may enter the student ID and the matching results will appear.
The problem is that whenever I use the ID option as the input, the do-while loops twice instead of just one. This is annoying because it will print the "CONSOLE>" message twice.

My sample input is "20180001"

More specific input/output on console:

```
Loop no: 0
CONSOLE>find
FIND >id
FIND ID >20180001
|   ID: 20180001    |    Name: Smith, John  |    Course: IT |    Year: 1st Year     |    Age: 18    |
Loop no: 1
CONSOLE>Loop no: 2
CONSOLE>
```

My expected output:

```
Loop no: 0
CONSOLE>find
FIND >id
FIND ID >20180001
|   ID: 20180001    |    Name: Smith, John  |    Course: IT |    Year: 1st Year     |    Age: 18    |
Loop no: 1
CONSOLE>
```

The error occurs here:

```
do {
            System.out.println("Loop no: " + temp);
            System.out.print("CONSOLE>");
            input = Scanner.nextLine();
```

Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String input = "";
        int input2 = 0;
        Student s0 = new Student();
        Student s1 = new Student();
        Student s2 = new Student();
        Student s3 = new Student();
        Student s4 = new Student();
        Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int temp = 0;

        fillStudents(s0, s1, s2, s3, s4);

        do {
            System.out.println("Loop no: " + temp);
            System.out.print("CONSOLE>");
            input = Scanner.nextLine();
            if (input.toUpperCase().equals("LIST STUDENTS")) {
                Student201.listStudents(s0, s1, s2, s3, s4);
            } /* else System.out.println("ERROR MESSAGE: '" + input + "' is not recognized "
                    + "as a command."); */
            if (input.toUpperCase().equals("FIND")) {
                System.out.print("FIND >");
                input = Scanner.nextLine();
                if (input.toUpperCase().equals("ID")) {
                    System.out.print("FIND ID >");
                    input2 = Scanner.nextInt();
                    if(s0.getStudentID() == input2) {
                        System.out.println(s0);
                    } /* else System.out.println("CONSOLE MESSAGE: No results were found with the first name '"
                            + input + "'."); */
                    if(s1.getStudentID() == input2) {
                        System.out.println(s1);
                    }
                    if(s2.getStudentID() == input2) {
                        System.out.println(s2);
                    }
                    if(s3.getStudentID() == input2) {
                        System.out.println(s3);
                    }
                    if(s4.getStudentID() == input2) {
                        System.out.println(s4);
                    }
                }
                if (input.toUpperCase().equals("FIRST NAME")) { // If the user chooses FIRST NAME to find students
                    System.out.print("FIND FIRST NAME >");
                    input = Scanner.nextLine();
                    if(s0.getFirstName().toUpperCase().equals(input.toUpperCase())) {
                        System.out.println(s0);
                    } /* else System.out.println("CONSOLE MESSAGE: No results were found with the first name '"
                            + input + "'."); */
                    if(s1.getFirstName().toUpperCase().equals(input.toUpperCase())) {
                        System.out.println(s1);
                    }
                    if(s2.getFirstName().toUpperCase().equals(input.toUpperCase())) {
                        System.out.println(s2);
                    }
                    if(s3.getFirstName().toUpperCase().equals(input.toUpperCase())) {
                        System.out.println(s3);
                    }
                    if(s4.getFirstName().toUpperCase().equals(input.toUpperCase())) {
                        System.out.println(s4);
                    }
                }
                if (input.toUpperCase().equals("LAST NAME")) { // If the user chooses LAST NAME to find students
                    System.out.print("FIND LAST NAME >");
                    input = Scanner.nextLine();
                    if(s0.getLastName().toUpperCase().equals(input.toUpperCase())) {
                        System.out.println(s0);
                    } /* else System.out.println("CONSOLE MESSAGE: No results were found with the last name '"
                            + input + "'."); */
                    if(s1.getLastName().toUpperCase().equals(input.toUpperCase())) {
                        System.out.println(s1);
                    }
                    if(s2.getLastName().toUpperCase().equals(input.toUpperCase())) {
                        System.out.println(s2);
                    }
                    if(s3.getLastName().toUpperCase().equals(input.toUpperCase())) {
                        System.out.println(s3);
                    }
                    if(s4.getLastName().toUpperCase().equals(input.toUpperCase())) {
                        System.out.println(s4);
                    }
                }

            }
        temp++;
        }while (!input.equals("exit"));

    }

    public static void fillStudents(Student s0, Student s1, Student s2, Student s3, Student s4) throws InterruptedException {

        clear();
        System.out.println("Filling the information of Students...");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        clear();

        s0.setLastName("Smith");
        s0.setFirstName("John");
        s0.setAge(18);
        s0.setCourse("IT");
        s0.setYear("1st Year");
        s0.setStudentID(20180001);

        s1.setLastName("Wallace");
        s1.setFirstName("Mark");
        s1.setAge(18);
        s1.setCourse("IT");
        s1.setYear("1st Year");
        s1.setStudentID(20180002);

        s2.setLastName("Reese");
        s2.setFirstName("Tony");
        s2.setAge(18);
        s2.setCourse("MA");
        s2.setYear("1st Year");
        s2.setStudentID(20180003);

        s3.setLastName("Johnson");
        s3.setFirstName("Liza");
        s3.setAge(18);
        s3.setCourse("BA");
        s3.setYear("1st Year");
        s3.setStudentID(20180004);

        s4.setLastName("Nguyen");
        s4.setFirstName("Kim");
        s4.setAge(17);
        s4.setCourse("ECE");
        s4.setYear("1st Year");
        s4.setStudentID(20180005);
    }

    public static void clear() {
        for(int x = 0; x<=100; x++) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Student class

```
package studentdirectory;

public class Student extends Student201{

    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String course;
    private String year;
    private int age;
    private int studentID;

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }
    public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "|\tID: " + this.getStudentID() + "\t|\t Name: " + this.getLastName() + ", "
                + this.getFirstName() + "\t|\t Course: " + this.getCourse() + "\t|\t Year: " +
                this.getYear() + "\t\t|\t Age: " + this.getAge() + "\t|";
    }

}
```

Student201 class

```
package studentdirectory;

public class Student201{
    public static void listStudents(Student s0, Student s1, Student s2, Student s3, Student s4) {
        System.out.println(s0);
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
        System.out.println(s3);
        System.out.println(s4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code _directly in the question_.  No one should/will have to go into your GitHub link to figure out what you are doing wrong.  Most likely this question is a duplicate anyway.

Comment: the code has 200 lines

Comment: @John_Sumitsu Then you should minimize it as much as you can to show the problem you're having.. Posting 200 lines might end up being too broad. I would suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also reading the [help guide on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Please give minimal code where you got error.

Comment: Cutting the code wouldn't make the code make sense because it's connected to other classes

Comment: in which class you are getting an error

Comment: edited the post to indicate where the error occurs

Comment: now its much better

Comment: thanks for teaching me

Comment: you are taking input twice in main class

Comment: yes. variable input for string and variable input2 for integer

Comment: oh yes I haven't see this.

Comment: I have edited the post to add the current output and my expected output

Comment: Your input are ID and 20180001?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix by putting "Scanner.nextLine();" right after "Scanner.nextInt();".
This stopped it from skipping input = Scanner.nextLine();

Comment: This approach will works but, if the code executes but the user don't want to do any operation and type "exit" then this will not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, came up with the solution. 
First of all the problem is not with the input the problem is in the do while `loop`
the do while loop first executes the statement and then check the `condition`.
What I did is I have created a `infinite loop` and then take the input and after input I have put the `condition`, if the `input` is Exit it breaks the `loop`.

Something like that

```
while (true){       
        input = Scanner.nextLine();
        if(input.toUpperCase().equals("EXIT"))
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
          // Put the whole logic inside this
        }
```

You have to do this otherwise the loop will automatically execute one time even if your input is `exit`.

Hopefully that helps

Comment: Thanks! I'll also try to use the debugging function on my IDE next time.

Comment: If this solution solves your problem don't forgot to mark on accept answer so that it will help future visitors also.